# Nested if into nested for in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I'm developing an application web in Python for a Burger shop, This app will get some data from a Data base and I need to manage this data

From the Data base I will get a list of tuples just like this one
check_table = [(1,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'medium'), (2,'Big', 'Cheddar', 'rare'), (3,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'rare')]

In here I trying to get the proper number of steaks according to their cooking level, Like rare, medium, Well-done

I spend a lot of time but I don't get the code to count properly, I even tried to make statements like

if check_table[x][y] == "Classic" and check_table[x][y] == "Rare":

steak += 1
rare +=1

Here's the code:

> ```
> check_table = [(1,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'Medium'), (2,'Big', 'Cheddar', 'Rare'), (3,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'Rare')]
>
> # Variables
> steaks = 0
> rare = 0
> medium = 0
> w_done = 0
>
> # Getting all the data from a nested for
> for x in range(len(check_table)):
>     for y in range(len(check_table[0])):
>         # Getting the number of steaks
>         if check_table[x][y] == "Classic":
>             steaks += 1
>             # Getting the style of the steak
>             if check_table[x][y] == "Rare":
>                 rare += 1
>             elif check_table[x][y] == 'Medium':
>                 medium += 1
>             elif check_table[x][y] == 'Well-done':
>                 w_done += 1
>
>         elif check_table[x][y] == "Big":
>             steaks += 2
>             # Getting steak style
>             if check_table[x][y] == 'Rare':
>                 rare += 2
>             elif check_table[x][y] == 'Medium':
>                 medium += 2
>             elif check_table[x][y] == 'Well-done':
>                 w_done += 2
>
> print("# Steaks ", steaks)
> print("# Rare ", rare)
> print("# Medium ", medium )
> print("# Well-done ", w_done)
> ```

I expected to get something like this
Steaks  4
rare  3
medium 1
Well-done  0

Because a classic burger contains one steak meanwhile the big one contains two steaks, instead I get this, like if the if statements were not there

Steaks  4
Rare  0
Medium  0
Well-done  0

Hope someone can help me with this one, Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check_table = [(1,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'Medium'), (2,'Big', 'Cheddar', 'Rare'), (3,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'Rare')]

# Variables
steaks = 0
rare = 0
medium = 0
w_done = 0

# Getting all the data from a nested for
for x in check_table:
    print(x)
      # Getting the number of steaks
    if x[1] == "Classic":
        steaks += 1
          # Getting the style of the steak
        if x[3] == "Rare":
            rare += 1
        elif x[3] == 'Medium':
            medium += 1
        elif x[3] == 'Well-done':
            w_done += 1

    elif x[1] == "Big":
        steaks += 2
          # Getting steak style
        if x[3] == 'Rare':
            rare += 2
        elif x[3] == 'Medium':
            medium += 2
        elif x[3] == 'Well-done':
            w_done += 2

print("# Steaks ", steaks)
print("# Rare ", rare)
print("# Medium ", medium )
print("# Well-done ", w_done)
```

Comment: Thanks man you just fixed my code, yeah I did it too complicated for nothing cheers man, ps sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

You should try to turn all those `if/elif` statements into lookups into some data structure. It will make everything easier to reason about, easier to edit, and it will make you code much more succinct.

For example instead of checking how many steaks with if/elif, just lookup how many steaks are in classic vs big:

```
steak_count = {
    'Classic': 1,
    'Big': 2
}
count = steak_count['Big'] # 2 steaks for 'Big'
```

Now if you add a different kind of burger you don't need to write a whole set of `if/elif` statements again. You can carry this idea to others with something like:

```
check_table = [(1,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'Medium'), (2,'Big', 'Cheddar', 'Rare'), (3,'Classic', 'Cheddar', 'Rare')]

steak_count = {
    'classic': 1,
    'big': 2
}
# Variables
counts = {
    'steaks': 0,
    'rare': 0,
    'medium': 0,
    'w_done': 0  
}

for order_num, steak, cheese, cooked in check_table:
    count = steak_count[steak.lower()]
    counts['steaks'] += count
    counts[cooked.lower()] += count

print(counts)
# {'steaks': 4, 'rare': 3, 'medium': 1, 'w_done': 0}
```

Comment: Really thank you Mark, that's a really interesting point of view, I will tested once I get some spare time to carry on the project and will back to you, cheers man

Comment: I really like your way of thinking, I wouldn't never think on coding like that really thanks man